# How to save boxplot automatically in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, boxplot

When I try to save boxplot using 'saveas' as follows

```
X = randn(10, 10);
H = boxplot(X);
saveas(H, 'x.fig');
```

I receive the error

```
??? Error using ==> saveas at 72
Simulink object array must be a vector.
```

This error shows up because H is a matrix of handles to the lines in the box plot, but saveas requires H to be a single handle. Can somebody tell me how to save boxplot using command? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SAVEAS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html) requires a handle to a figure as its first input. [BOXPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/boxplot.html), like most other plotting functions, return the handles of the plotted graphical objects, but not the figure handle.

Thus, you should write `saveas(gcf,'x.fig')`, which uses [GCF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gcf.html) to query the handle of the current figure, which is the figure into which the boxplot has been plotted.